# How to send null values using jaxrs-jsonb (JSON-B | JSR-367)?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, wildfly, thorntail

I am working in a legacy system with Java/EJB/JPA/thorntail/wildfly.

The project has:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-jsonb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
```

JSON-B provides support for JSON Processing according to JSR-367.

I need to send null values in API/Rest. Anything similar to `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` for Jackson.

Example that I need:

```
PersonApi with name=Any, age=null

{
    "name": "Any",
    "age": null
}
```

Is there some config to do this? ... some annotation, some config to load and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbNillable` annotation:

```java
@JsonbNillable
public static class PersonApi {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    //constructors, getters and setters are omitted
}
```

Comment: I will try but in this project, the java ee version is 7 and I think that this annotation have been created in java ee 8.

Comment: @leandro.dev I've checked `io.thorntail.jaxrs-jsonb.2.6.0.Final` (from your question) with `org.eclipse.yasson.1.0.6` and everything works fine.